# Need verification (and an alternative, if that's possible) for proof on generalization of direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, alternative-proof

I tried to write a proof for this theorem and I would like verification on it. I would also appreciate an alternative (perhaps shorter) proof:

*Let V be a K - Vector Space. The following statements are equivalent:*

*1. There is a decomposition of $V=W_1\oplus...\oplus W_n$*

*2. There exist projections $e_i:V \to V / Id_V= \sum_{i=1}^n e_i$ , $e_i\circ e_j=e_j\circ e_i= 0$ and $Im(e_i)=W_i$*

**My proof:**

**$1 \Rightarrow 2$ //**

Since $V=W_1 \oplus ... \oplus W_n$ ,  $\exists$ n projections $e_i:V \to V / V=Ker(e_i)\oplus Im(e_i)$ , $i=1,...,n$

We can define the projections in such a way that $Im(e_j)=W_j$ and $Ker(e_j)=\oplus _{i\neq j} W_i$ :

Let $v=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i \in V$ , with $v_i \in W_i$, and let's define $e_i(v)=v_i$ , $i=1,...,n$

- Let's prove it is a linear map:

Let $\lambda \in K$ and $u, v \in V$ , where $u=\sum_{i=1}^n u_i$ and $v=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i$ , $u_i, v_i \in W_i$ :

$$e_j(\lambda u+v)=e_j\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda u_i+v_i \bigg)=\lambda u_j+v_j=\lambda e_j(u)+e_j(v)$$

- Now let's prove it's a projection:

$$e_i^2(v)=e_i(e_i(v))=e_i(v_i)=v_i =e_i(v)$$

- Now let's verify that $Nu(e_j)=\oplus_{i\neq j} W_i$ and $Im(e_j)=W_j$ :

If $v\in \oplus_{i \neq j} W_i$ , then $v=\sum_{i\neq j}v_i$ and $e_j(v)=0 \Longrightarrow \oplus_{i\neq j} W_i\subset Ker(e_i)$

Let $v \in Ker(e_j) \Rightarrow e_j(v)=0 \forall i=1,...,n$ , but we also have that $v=v_j+\sum_{i\neq j}v_i \Rightarrow e_j(v)=v_j$

Then $v_j=0$ and $v=\sum_{i\neq j} v_i \in \oplus_{i\neq j} W_i \Longrightarrow Ker(e_i) \subset W_i$

$$\therefore Ker(e_j)=\oplus_{i\neq j} W_i \;\; \forall j=1,...,n$$

Let $w \in Im(e_i) \Rightarrow \exists u \in V / e_i(u)=w=v_i \in W_i \Longrightarrow Im(e_i) \subset W_i$

Let $v_i \in W_i \Rightarrow e_i(v_I)=v_i \in Im(e_i) \Longrightarrow W_i \in Im(e_i)$

$$\therefore Im(e_i)=W_i \;\; \forall i=1,..,n$$

- We have just proven that $Im(e_i)=W_i$, so are left to prove that $Id_V= \sum_{i=1}^n e_i$ and $e_i\circ e_j=e_j\circ e_i= 0$ :

Let $v \in V$ , then:

$$\Rightarrow v=\sum_{i=i}^n v_i = \sum_{i=i}^n e_i(v) \Rightarrow Id_V(v)= \sum_{i=i}^n e_i(v) \;\; \forall v \in V$$

$$\therefore Id_V= \sum_{i=1}^n e_i$$

$$\Rightarrow e_i\circ e_j(v)=e_i(v_j)=0 \;\; (e_j \circ e_i \; is \; analogous)$$

$$\therefore e_i\circ e_j=e_j\circ e_i= 0$$

**$2 \Rightarrow 1$//**

Assume that $\exists$ n projections  $e_i:V \to V$ $/Id_v=\sum_{i=1}^n e_i$ , $e_i\circ e_j=e_j\circ e_i= 0$ and $Im(e_i)=W_i$

Let $v\in V$, then $Id_V(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n e_i(v) \in \sum_{i=1}^n W_i$ $\forall v\in V$

$$\therefore V=W_1+...+W_n$$

Assume there is a $v\in \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n W_i$   , then $v=e_i(v)$ $\forall i=1,...,n$

So $e_i\circ e_j(v)=e_i(v)=v=0$

$$\therefore \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n W_i = {0} \;\; and \;\; V=\oplus_{i=1}^n W_i$$

$$\blacksquare$$

Comment: $1\Rightarrow2$ is too verbous. Simply define $e_i$ as *the* projection (known to be linear) with range $W_i$ and kernel the complementary subspace $\oplus_{j\ne i}W_j,$ and only keep the last bullet. And no need of "($e_j \circ e_i$ is analogous)": it is built in since you proved it for any *distinct* indices $i,j$ (btw, you forgot to mention *distinct* everywhere).

Comment: The 2nd half of $2\Rightarrow 1$ is not sufficient to prove that [the sum of the $n$ subspaces is direct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640784/). E.g. in $\Bbb R^3,$ three distinct planes have a zero-intersection without being in direct sum.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't quite get why it is not sufficient, as $v \in \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n W_i$ implies $v \in Im(e_i) \forall i=1,...,n$ and the composition implies $v \in Ker(e_i)$, and as e is a projection $Im(e_i) \cap Ker(e_i)={0} \Rightarrow v=0$?

Comment: I gave you a counterexample and a link. $v\in\cap W_i\Rightarrow v=0$ is true but not sufficient.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yeah, I checked the link. Then, given that e is defined such that $Im(e_j)=W_j$, would proving that $Ker(e_j)=\sum_{i\neq j} W_i$ to use the statement $V_i \cap \sum_{i \neq j} V_i = {0}$ be sufficient?

Comment: Sufficient but not necessary. It is easier to prove only that $W_i\cap\sum_{j\ne i}W_j=\{0\}.$